Getting null when i try to mock restTemplate.GetForObject - kotlin
I have a service function something akin to this:
class serviceClass
private fun getThings(personID: Long): List<myDTO> {
        val url = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl("http://webpage/{personID}")
            .buildAndExpand(personID)
            .toUri()

        val response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String::class.java)
        return response?.let { objectMapper.readValue(it) } ?: emptyList()
    }

and this is my test:
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Mock
    private lateinit var myClient: MyClient

    @Mock
    private lateinit var restTemplate: RestTemplate

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var serviceClass: ServiceClass

    @Test
    fun myTest() {
        // ARRANGE
        val testID = 123L

        val varslingsmottaker = lagVarslingsmottaker(testID)

        val data = makeData(testID)

        val clientResponse = listOf(data)

        val responseFromURL = makeResponseFromURL(testID)

        whenever(restTemplate.getForObject(any<String>(),  eq(String::class.java))).thenReturn(responseFromURL)

        whenever(myClient.getContacts(any())).thenReturn(clientResponse)

        // ACT
        val fullPerson = serviceClass.get(testID)

    }

The problem is, whenever I try this (tried several was of writing the first whenever statement) I always get an error, as my restTemplate.getForObject only returns null.
Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?
I'm expecting the whenever to return the correct value test value.
I've tried many ways of writing
whenever(restTemplate.getForObject(any<String>(),  eq(String::class.java))).thenReturn(responseFromURL)

, also tried changing it all to gerForEntity.
